# how to retrieve an individual song from spotify, using spotifys API

Tags: javascript

How do I use the Spotify Api to retrieve an individual known song that I  search for and pick, for example: I want James Brown(Artist) And living in America(the song), how do I retrieve just this one song and display it on my app to be played using Javascript. so far I read through the Spotify Api, but seems like you can only get back a whole playlist, or Album, but I just want one song.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: A combination of https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/ and https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-track/ should do the trick. Get the items, filter for your item, get the track id and than query the track. Never worked with the spotify API but it seems straight foward.

Answer (score 0):

When generating the code from Spotify.developer API: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/
set the limit input to 1 (to get only 1 track as a result).

or manually as in the example you gave above the code will look like this;

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=remaster%2520track%3Aliving%2520in%2520America%2520artist%3AJames%2520Brown&type=track%2Cartist&market=ES&limit=1&offset=5" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "
```

note that limit is set to 1

**limit=1**

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i'll report back soon to see if it works